# telegram-bot в общем чате

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

Сделал простого telegram-бота:

```
import telebot
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def repeat_all_messages(message):
    if (message.text.split(" ")[0].upper() == 'BOT,'):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'I\'m here')
```

Все отлично работает, но когда добавляю его в групповой чат, то он молчит. Подскажите, как сделать его адаптированным к групповым чатам ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Вариантов несколько:**

1. Можно обращаться к боту через слеш `/` - `/YourMessage`, если в
   группе несколько ботов, то с упоминанием его юзернейма -
   `/YourMessage@YourBotName`.
2. Можно задать боту список команд с помощью @BotFather, тогда при вводе слеша пользователь увидит список всех доступных команд и сможет выбрать нужную.
3. Можно отключить `privacy mode`, тогда к бот будет получать все сообщения от группы, кроме сообщений от других ботов. По умолчанию `privacy mode` включен.
4. Можно сделать бота администратором группы, что так же позволит получать все сообщения от группы, кроме сообщений от других ботов.

> **What messages will my bot get?**
>
> Your bot will receive all messages
>   from users in one-on-one chats. Privacy mode only applies to messages
>   in groups (or supergroups).
>
> Privacy mode is always disabled if your bot is an admin in the group.
>   For supergroups, privacy mode is set to what your bot was using when
>   it joined the group — if you change it later, you'll need to remove
>   the bot and add it again for changes to take effect. By default, your
>   bot runs in privacy mode and only sees the following messages in
>   groups (or supergroups):
>
> Replies to the bot's own messages (messages sent via a custom keyboard
>   are always a reply to the bot). Commands from users meant for your bot
>   (e.g. /start@YourBot). General commands from users (e.g. /start) if
>   your bot was the last bot that sent a message to the group. Service
>   messages (e.g. when somebody leaves or joins a group, group name or
>   photo changes, etc.). If your bot is an admin or if privacy mode is
>   disabled, your bot will get all messages sent to the group, except for
>   messages from other bots.

[Ссылка](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#what-messages-will-my-bot-get)