# Telegram Webhook, сканирование чата

Tags: telegram-bot

Есть ли способ сканировать чат группы через webhook по аналогии getupdates, чтобы получать объект сообщения, который был адресован не боту, а просто написан в чате?

Comment: Должен быть точно :) :) :) Хуебот же добавляет изменяя слова собеседников )

Comment: Поискал пишут нужно отключить приватность бота, тогда при помощи getUpdates он будет видеть все сообщения

Answer (score 1):

Без разницы, Webhook это или GetUpdates, это работает одинаково. Вам нужно ловить **update**`ы с типом **message**, если это группа и **channel_post**, если это канал.

Про доступность посмотрите [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/561378/183842).

Answer (score 0):

**/setprivacy** — set which messages your bot will receive when added to a group. With privacy mode disabled, the bot will receive all messages. We recommend leaving privacy mode enabled.

В отключенном состоянии бот будет получать все сообщения в группе.
Подробнее в [документации](https://core.telegram.org/bots)