# Простой Telegram Bot Java отвечает в лс, но не хочет в чаты

Tags: java, telegram-bot, telegrambots

Всем привет, не могу понять почему телеграм бот не хочет отвечать в беседы, только в лс работает нормально, вот код

```java
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        if (update.getMessage().getText().equals("/films")){
            try {
                SendMessage outMessage = new SendMessage();
                outMessage.setChatId(update.getMessage().getChatId().toString());
                outMessage.setText("Таблица фильмов доступна по ссылке: ***");
                execute(outMessage);
            } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

И всё работает нормально для лс, но не для бесед. Кто-то знает почему?

Код ниже например, отвечал и в беседы

```java
public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        try {
            if (update.hasMessage() && update.getMessage().hasText()) {
                Message inMessage = update.getMessage();
                SendMessage outMessage = new SendMessage();
                outMessage.setChatId(String.valueOf(inMessage.getChatId()));
                outMessage.setText("Таблица фильмов доступна по ссылке: ***);
                execute(outMessage);
            }
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Вот какая-то ошибка, только еще не понял что её триггерит

```java
13:52:04.167 [x Telegram Executor] ERROR org.telegram.telegrambots.updatesreceivers.DefaultBotSession - Cannot invoke "org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Message.getText()" because the return value of "org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Update.getMessage()" is null
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Message.getText()" because the return value of "org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Update.getMessage()" is null
    at x.bot.x.onUpdateReceived(x.java:13)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.generics.LongPollingBot.onUpdatesReceived(LongPollingBot.java:27)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.updatesreceivers.DefaultBotSession$HandlerThread.run(DefaultBotSession.java:317)
```

---

Вот текущий код:

```java
package x.bot;

import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send.SendMessage;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Update;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiException;

public class x extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update){
        if (update.hasMessage() && "/films".equals(update.getMessage().getText())){
            try{
                SendMessage outMessage = new SendMessage();
                outMessage.setChatId(update.getMessage().getChatId().toString());
                outMessage.setText("Таблица фильмов доступна по ссылке: ***");
                execute(outMessage);
            }
            catch (TelegramApiException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public String getBotToken() {
        return "***";
    }

    public String getBotUsername() {
        return "x";
    }

}
```

Main:

```java
package x.bot;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.TelegramBotsApi;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiException;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.updatesreceivers.DefaultBotSession;


public class Main {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            TelegramBotsApi telegramBotsApi = new TelegramBotsApi(DefaultBotSession.class);
            telegramBotsApi.registerBot(new x());
        }
        catch (TelegramApiException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Бот в личные сообщения отвечает на /films нормально: [image: скрин]
В беседах же на команду /films не отзывается вообще: [image: скрин2]
При этом бот админ, команда создана, privacy mode выключен

Ошибок нет

Добавил

```java
System.out.println("update received: " + update.toString());
```

Вот что вышло

1 это лс

```java
update received: Update(updateId=213901835, message=Message(messageId=461, from=User(id=426678678, firstName=₭єҝσċƙ, isBot=false, lastName=null, userName=kekock, languageCode=ru, canJoinGroups=null, canReadAllGroupMessages=null, supportInlineQueries=null), date=1628432492, chat=Chat(id=426678678, type=private, title=null, firstName=₭єҝσċƙ, lastName=null, userName=kekock, allMembersAreAdministrators=null, photo=null, description=null, inviteLink=null, pinnedMessage=null, stickerSetName=null, canSetStickerSet=null, permissions=null, slowModeDelay=null, bio=null, linkedChatId=null, location=null, messageAutoDeleteTime=null), forwardFrom=null, forwardFromChat=null, forwardDate=null, text=/films, entities=[MessageEntity(type=bot_command, offset=0, length=6, url=null, user=null, language=null, text=/films)], captionEntities=null, audio=null, document=null, photo=null, sticker=null, video=null, contact=null, location=null, venue=null, animation=null, pinnedMessage=null, newChatMembers=[], leftChatMember=null, newChatTitle=null, newChatPhoto=null, deleteChatPhoto=null, groupchatCreated=null, replyToMessage=null, voice=null, caption=null, superGroupCreated=null, channelChatCreated=null, migrateToChatId=null, migrateFromChatId=null, editDate=null, game=null, forwardFromMessageId=null, invoice=null, successfulPayment=null, videoNote=null, authorSignature=null, forwardSignature=null, mediaGroupId=null, connectedWebsite=null, passportData=null, forwardSenderName=null, poll=null, replyMarkup=null, dice=null, viaBot=null, senderChat=null, proximityAlertTriggered=null, messageAutoDeleteTimerChanged=null, voiceChatStarted=null, voiceChatEnded=null, voiceChatParticipantsInvited=null, voiceChatScheduled=null), inlineQuery=null, chosenInlineQuery=null, callbackQuery=null, editedMessage=null, channelPost=null, editedChannelPost=null, shippingQuery=null, preCheckoutQuery=null, poll=null, pollAnswer=null, myChatMember=null, chatMember=null)
```

2 это беседа-чат

```java
update received: Update(updateId=213901836, message=Message(messageId=152, from=User(id=426678678, firstName=₭єҝσċƙ, isBot=false, lastName=null, userName=kekock, languageCode=ru, canJoinGroups=null, canReadAllGroupMessages=null, supportInlineQueries=null), date=1628432590, chat=Chat(id=-1001575358066, type=supergroup, title=мы и бот, firstName=null, lastName=null, userName=null, allMembersAreAdministrators=null, photo=null, description=null, inviteLink=null, pinnedMessage=null, stickerSetName=null, canSetStickerSet=null, permissions=null, slowModeDelay=null, bio=null, linkedChatId=null, location=null, messageAutoDeleteTime=null), forwardFrom=null, forwardFromChat=null, forwardDate=null, text=/films@x, entities=[MessageEntity(type=bot_command, offset=0, length=23, url=null, user=null, language=null, text=/films@x)], captionEntities=null, audio=null, document=null, photo=null, sticker=null, video=null, contact=null, location=null, venue=null, animation=null, pinnedMessage=null, newChatMembers=[], leftChatMember=null, newChatTitle=null, newChatPhoto=null, deleteChatPhoto=null, groupchatCreated=null, replyToMessage=null, voice=null, caption=null, superGroupCreated=null, channelChatCreated=null, migrateToChatId=null, migrateFromChatId=null, editDate=null, game=null, forwardFromMessageId=null, invoice=null, successfulPayment=null, videoNote=null, authorSignature=null, forwardSignature=null, mediaGroupId=null, connectedWebsite=null, passportData=null, forwardSenderName=null, poll=null, replyMarkup=null, dice=null, viaBot=null, senderChat=null, proximityAlertTriggered=null, messageAutoDeleteTimerChanged=null, voiceChatStarted=null, voiceChatEnded=null, voiceChatParticipantsInvited=null, voiceChatScheduled=null), inlineQuery=null, chosenInlineQuery=null, callbackQuery=null, editedMessage=null, channelPost=null, editedChannelPost=null, shippingQuery=null, preCheckoutQuery=null, poll=null, pollAnswer=null, myChatMember=null, chatMember=null)
```

Comment: В onUpdateReceived вообще заходит при поступлении команды из группового чата? Ошибки какие-нибудь выдаёт? Что в логе показывается?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [telegram-bot в общем чате](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/558427/telegram-bot-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5)

Comment: Если команда не начинается с `/`, то бот такие команды не увидит. А чтобы увидел, нужно изменить privacy mode в настройках бота (через бота для создания ботов BotFather)

Comment: @Vadik нет, это не мой случай ибо команда есть, доступ к сообщениям у него есть, он админ, но не отвечает

Comment: @kami добавил вроде ошибку

Comment: У вас Null Pointer Exception, ознакомтесь [Что такое Null Pointer Exception и как его исправить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511085)

Comment: Дело в том, что message может прийти пустым, вам его надо проверить на `null`. Либо делать проверку `update.hasMessage()`, прежде чем работать с `update.getMessage()`.

Comment: Залоггируйте, что приходит в `update`, и [приложите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1315205/edit) в вопрос. Сделать это можно, например, так: напишите в самом начале метода `onUpdateReceived` строчку: `System.out.println("update received: " + update.toString());` и посмотрите в логах.

Comment: @Vadik вроде дополнил

Comment: Вы отправляете сообщение `"/films@VashRabotyagaBot"`, а в коде проверяете на `"/films"`.

Comment: @Vadik боже столько проблем из-за этой фигни, это же автоматически телеграм так вызывает команды ботов в беседах, я даже и не подумал что с этим могут быть проблемы. 

Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не учли в вашем коде, что вызов `update.getMessage()` может вернуть `null`. Чтобы обезопаситься от ошибки, необходимо добавить прверку на `null`:

```java
update.getMessage() != null && update.getMessage().getText().equals("/films")
```

Либо воспользоваться методом `hasMessage()`, который делает по сути то же самое:

```java
update.hasMessage() && update.getMessage().getText().equals("/films")
```

То же самое касается вызова `getText()`, он может вернуть `null`, чтобы избежать очередного NPE, можно написать [так](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%99%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B#%D0%90%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8):

```java
update.hasMessage() && "/films".equals(update.getMessage().getText())
```

Comment: Может быть проблема с getChatId бесед? 
хотя что меняется от второго кода который работает в беседы

Comment: "но ничего не изменилось" -- в логах та же ошибка или уже новая? приложите ее в вопрос.

Comment: вы уже разобрались из-за чего в Java возникает [Null Pointer Exception](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511085)?

Comment: Может быть вы не `/films` пишете боту, а что-то другое? Вы это не указали в вашем вопросе: "бот не хочет отвечать в беседы", что именно вы ему пишете? Отредактируйте вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

В итоге если добавить

```java
if (update.hasMessage() && "/films@x".equals(update.getMessage().getText()) || "/films".equals(update.getMessage().getText())){
```

Бот будет отвечать и в лс, и в беседы

И на просто /films из лс и на /films@x из бесед

Comment: Только скобочек не хватает, у `&&` приоритет выше, чем у `||`. Сравните: `a && b || c` и `a && (b || c)`

Comment: @Vadik хорошо, спасибо